# Running a PHP script

Tags: php, cakephp

I need keep running the PHP script but I have a problem, currently I use putty to login to the server then execute PHP code. When I close putty session the script stops the execution.

Steps:

1. login to server with putty
2. running PHP script eg) PHP filename

but when I close the putty session the program will obvious close. I need to keep running the program on server regardless of closing putty and anyone logging into server can stop it and run it again as a process. How to run a php script independent of putty session, which can be controlled by anyone logging to server?

Comment: Read about `Cron jobs` http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Comment: cron job will not be helpful since it needs to specify a time for triggering it, but my script needs to be kept running for processing the input as they come in..

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui cron jobs are for the automatic execution of a script at a set interval. They do not have anything to do with a script exiting prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your question is really in the scope of programming, it is more a unix/linux specific question of "How to run a program from shell that doesn't close when I close the terminal". PHP happens to be that program.

You can do `php -f scriptname.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null & disown`.

STDOUT and STDERR will be redirected to /dev/null (or you can change those to real files) and the ambersand will fork the process. Disown will remove the running PID from the terminal session.

Comment: how do i close it and run it again if changes where made? whether killing the process can be done by anyone who are logging to server or it can be done by only me or who has started it?

Comment: To kill it you need the PID which can be found with `ps -A`. But again, this is not a programming question.

Comment: Whether disowning process by this method, can be seen in process list when logging through other user?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to fork the process before you terminate it. This way when you exit the process (or close your ssh connection) the secondary process will continue to run.

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
  die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
  // parent
  pcntl_wait($status);
} else {
  // child
  // write your code here!
}
```

Comment: by forking process, how do i close it and run it again if changes where made? whether killing the process can be done by anyone who are logging to server or it can be done by only me or who has started it?